# C++ Regarding strcmp and read file

Tags: c++

I got a code at main.cpp

```
cout<<endl<<"Please enter filename: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,fileName);
fin.open(fileName.c_str());
if(fin.is_open())
{

    while(fin.good())
    {
        fin.getline(line,20,',');

        if(!strcmp(line,"Map2D")) 
        {
            cout << "Map 2D" << endl;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(line,"Map3D")) 
        {
            cout << "Map 3D" << endl;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(line,"Dot2D")) 
        {
            cout << "Dot 2D" << endl;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(line,"Dot3D")) 
        {
            cout << "Dot 3D" << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

This is my text file

```
Map2D, [3, 8]
Dot3D, [7, 12, 3], [-9, 13, 68]
Map3D, [1, 3, 8]
Dot2D, [5, 7], [3, 8]
Map2D, [6, 2]
```

But the issue is when i try to compile and run, it keep print map2D and the Map3d wont even be cout

is there wrong with my logic on strcmp

**Update:**

I changed to if(strstr(line,"Map2D") and its work.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: First of all, the code in your snippet won't compile, there is no `elseif` in C++. Also, you should not loop on `fin.good()`, instead put `fin.getline(...)` in the condition. Thirdly, what is the declaration of `line`? And lastly, have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger, it will help you see the contents of all variables.

Comment: sorry typo should be else if

Comment: It would be nice to copy paste enough code to compile and try. Apparently fin.getline fails without consuming the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getline` is not reading lines, but until it encounters the next ",".

I.e., you iterate over:

```
Map2D
 [3
 8]\nDot3D
 [7
 12
 3]
 [-9
 13
 68]\nMap3D
...
```

It should be easy to see why you don't ever hit a token equaling "Map3D".

By the way, the code you pasted is not the code you compiled. There is no such thing as "elseif" in C++.

Comment: I changed to strstr and the issue is fixed. thanks for helping.

Comment: @user1777711: The better thing would be to read the whole line, *then* parse each token (e.g. by using `istringstream`). Swallowing newlines mid-token like that isn't really good style.

Comment: @DevSolar user1777711 has already been given this advice. I guess he'll figure it out for himself soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code, some of which are clearly
unrelated to your problem, but I'll take them in order:

- The `cin.ignore()` is going to require the user to enter an extra,
  empty line.
- The `while ( fin.good() )` is certainly wrong; in fact, there is never
  a case where `fin.good()` would be appropriate.  You probably want
  `while ( fin.getline( line, 20, ',' ) )` here.
- You don't verify whether `fin.getline` succeeded or not before using
  the results.
- You only read up to the next comma each time through the loop, so your
  input is something like `"Map2D"`, `" [3"`, `" 8]\nDot3D"`, `" [7"`...
- `strcmp` returns an `int`, not a `bool`, with `0` for equality, so you
  should be writing `if ( strcmp( line, "..." ) == 0 )` unless your intent
  is explicit obfuscation.  (Similarly, naming the input variable `line`
  when it only contains a single comma separated field is also
  obfuscation.)

The correct way to do something like this is probably to use
`std::string` to read the complete line, then parse the line itself
using any number of standard tools.  Something like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( fin, line ) ) {
    std::string label
        = std::string( line.begin(),
                       std::find( line.begin(), line.end(), ',' ) );
    if ( label == "Map2D" ) {
        //  ...
    } else if ( label == "Map3D" ) {
        //  ...
    } // ...
}
```